# decision tree always returns the same value for different inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, decision-tree

I am new to coding. I am learning machine learning with python. Using decision tree, I trying to predict chance for heart attack of individual using dataset from Kaggle. After modeling when I try to predict for different inputs it is always returning same output [1]. What may be the problem? What can I do? This my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
heart=pd.read_csv('heart_attack.csv')
heart.fillna(heart.mean(),inplace=True)
x=heart.iloc[:,:-1]
y=heart.iloc[:,-1]
import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
x=x.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20, random_state=85)
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
result=DecisionTreeClassifier()
result.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred=result.predict(x_test)
```

This is the code where i store the input values

```
Patient_Data = [Patient_Age,Patient_Gender,Patient_pain,Patient_RBP,Patient_chol,Patient_FBS,Patient_ECG,Patient_thalach,Patient_exang,Patient_oldpeak,Patient_slope,Patient_thal]
Patient_Data_New= pd.DataFrame([Patient_Data],columns=['Age','Gender','cp','restbps','chol','FBS','restecg','thalach','exang','oldpeak','slope', 'thal'])
Patient= result.predict(Patient_Data_New)
if Patient>0:
print ('This patient has a chance to get heart attack')
else:
print ('This patient does not have a chance to get heart attack')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some samples from heart_attack.csv

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are predicting values for data which is already present in the training set, hence your model is able to predict all the values correctly thus giving 100 percent accuracy.

try this

`result.score`

if the result is 100 percent then it's an example of overfitting and you need to drop a few columns andfind the best params using **k-fold cross validation**.